# Sum of random variables of normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Is it true that if

$$ X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) $$

then

$$ Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \sim N(n\mu, n\sigma^2) $$

where $N$ is the normal distribution and $X_i$ are independent random variables?

If it is so, how can I prove something like this?

Comment: **Hint:** Central Limit Theorem

Comment: Try to use the characteristic function.

Comment: Several proofs are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables).

Comment: @Myridium What does it have to do with the central limit theorem? It is only a finite sum of normal random variables.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb - right you are. I need to stop staying up late reading MSE.

Comment: Wait, no, my comment does serve a purpose. Your expression for $Y$ is wrong in the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating $E(e^{i\omega X})$ for each $X_i$ gives us:

$$\large\Phi_{X}(\omega)=e^{-{{\sigma^2\omega^2}\over 2}}e^{-i\omega\mu}$$

which is equal to all i.i.d $X_i$'s. Now for calculating the same characteristic function for $Y=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ we have:

$$\large\Phi_Y(\omega)=E(e^{i\omega Y}$$$$\large=E(e^{i\omega{\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}X_i}})$$$$\large=E(e^{i\omega X_1}e^{i\omega X_2}...e^{i\omega X_n})$$$$\large=E(e^{i\omega X_1})E(e^{i\omega X_2})...E(e^{i\omega X_n})$$$$\large={\Phi_X^{n}(\omega)}=e^{-{{n\sigma^2\omega^2}\over 2}}e^{-in\omega\mu}$$

which is corresponding to $Y\sim N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$